# structure double output

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

```
struct node
{
    double a : 23;
    int b;
}s;
int main()
{    
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(s));
}
```

Why do this produce a compile error? I want to know why we cannot do bit-fields with double datatype.

Comment: You can only specify bitfields for integer types - think about it - how could this possibly work with a floating point type ?

Comment: That's harsh -- with some effort someone could invent a reasonable meaning for a floating-point bifield, even if the resulting code would be painfully slow.  But C and C++ don't have such a feature, so I say @dasblinkenlight wins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from Wiki :

> C also provides a special type of structure member known as a bit field, which is an integer with an explicitly specified number of bits. A bit field is declared as a structure member of type int, signed int, unsigned int, or _Bool, following the member name by a colon (:) and the number of bits it should occupy. The total number of bits in a single bit field must not exceed the total number of bits in its declared type.

in the statement `double a : 23;` you are using bit field for double which is an error.You should use int instead.

Edit:
The Behavior is implementation dependent use anything other than these.Char may work on your system but it may fail on other platform as it's not part of standard.

Comment: The behavior is implementation-defined if you use anything other than _Bool, signed int, or unsigned int.

Comment: @Arya char is an integral type.

Comment: Blockquote formatting is a much better option for block-level quotations than quotation marks. It's much harder to miss.

Comment: @CodyGray:thnx...i will take care of that next time

Answer (score 5):

My answer is for C. I have no idea if it applies to C++.
I suggest you do not try to write multi-language source files. It is hard work.

- no prototype in scope for `printf`
- type of `sizeof(s)` and type required by `"%d"` do not match
- missing `return 0;` in main (for C89)

What compiler error do you get?

---

> I want to know that we can not do bitwise with double datatype

Because [the C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says so, eg (emphasis is mine)

> 6.7.2.1/9
>
> A bit-ﬁeld is interpreted as a **signed or unsigned integer type** consisting of the speciﬁed
>   number of bits.

Comment: C++0x §9.6/3: "A bit-field shall have integral or enumeration type." so that applies to C++ as well.

Comment: hi rest are just warnings I want to know whether double is allowed with bitwise

Answer (score 4):

> C provides a special type of structure member known as a bit field, which is an [integer with an explicitly specified number of bits.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Bit_fields)

Non-integral types cannot be used as base types for bit fields.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, You can't apply bit fields for double ,that's why it is giving compilation error.
Bit fiels are allowed only for  signed & unsigned int ,_bool data type.